# Jquery Custom DropDown Does Not Work On Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote a bit of code to replace jquery dropdowns to those found in twitter bootstrap.
http://jsfiddle.net/xuAQv/6/

Unfortunately the code just does not run correctly in IE versions 9 or less.
I have no idea how to debug the code and after trying to lint the code am still having issues.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are `xSelect`, `xLabel` and `xClass`? They are not defined in your fiddle :)

Comment: sorry wrong version : http://jsfiddle.net/xuAQv/6/

Comment: xSelect = the id of the select box.  xClass = a data value to select bootstrap class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.
It was an internet explorer issue with Jquery Prepend.
For anyone that is interested the code is now on jsfidde:
http://jsfiddle.net/xuAQv/13/